# Amazon AWS RDS Create database permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008, amazon-rds

I created an AWS RDS MSSQL instance using Management Console but I cannot create a new database. Creating a table works fine though.

Did I miss anything in the configuration? Do I need to execute a special schema?

Comment: Hi @sheeks06, did you find out eventually what the solution to this is?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can create up to 30 databases per RDS instances.
http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#2

We would need more details to debug your particular issue. (Parameters used to create the RDS instance, exact error message etc )